# Update upcoming values in sink if needed

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm currently trying to modify an upcoming value from a textField which is using a `Binding<Double>`, but haven't found any working solution yet. It's only been infinite loops (Like the example below) and other solutions which didn't work in the end anyway. So, for example, if an user inputs an amount which is too low, I would want to change the upcoming value to the minimum and vice verse if the value is higher than the maximum value.

I also want to present the `modified` value (if needed) for the user, so I can't just store it in another variable.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

#### Example

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var amount: Double

    private var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    private let minimum: Double = 10_000
    private let maximum: Double = 100_000

    init() {
        $amount
            .sink {
                if $0 < self.minimum {
                    // Set minimum value
                    self.amount = self.minimum
                } else if $0 > self.maximum {
                    // Set maximum value
                    self.amount = self.maximum
                }

                // If `Else` is implemented it will just be an infinite loop...
                else {
                    self.amount = $0
                }
            }
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }

    func prepareStuff() {
        // Start preparing
        let chosenAmount = amount
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use a property wrapper to clamp the values.

Here is a very basic example of the issue, where we have an `amount`, that we can change to any value. The `Stepper` just makes it easy for input/testing:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var amount = 0

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Stepper("Amount", value: $amount)

            Text(String(amount))
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this example is that `amount` isn't limited to a range. To fix this, create a `Clamping` property wrapper (partially from [here](https://nshipster.com/propertywrapper/#implementing-a-value-clamping-property-wrapper)):

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Clamping<Value: Comparable> {
    private var value: Value
    let range: ClosedRange<Value>

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { value }
        set { value = min(max(range.lowerBound, newValue), range.upperBound) }
    }
    var clampedValue: Value {
        get { wrappedValue }
        set { wrappedValue = newValue }
    }

    init(wrappedValue value: Value, _ range: ClosedRange<Value>) {
        precondition(range.contains(value))
        self.value = value
        self.range = range
    }
}
```

And then we can chain property wrappers, and get a working example where `amount` is limited:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State @Clamping(-5 ... 5) private var amount = 0

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Stepper("Amount", value: $amount.clampedValue)

            Text(String(amount))
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>I know, this isn't the proper way to limit a `Stepper`'s range. Instead you should use `Stepper(_:value:in:)`. However, this is to instead demonstrate clamping a value - **not** how to clamp a `Stepper`.</sup>

#### What does this mean you need to do?

Well, first off change your `@Published` property to this:

```
@Published @Clamping(10_000 ... 100_000) var amount: Double
```

And now you can just access `amount` like normal to get the *clamped* value. Use `$amount.clampedValue` like I did in my solution to get your `Binding<Double>` binding.

---

If having troubles sometimes with compiling chained property wrappers (probably a bug), here is my example recreated using a `Model` object and `@Published`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var model = Model(amount: 0)

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Stepper("Amount", value: $model.amount.clampedValue)

            Text(String(model.amount.clampedValue))
        }
    }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var amount: Clamping<Int>

    init(amount: Int) {
        _amount = Published(wrappedValue: Clamping(wrappedValue: amount, -5 ... 5))
    }
}
```

Comment: Really nice solution! After looking for some hours after a solution I found out I could just use the `OnCommit` parameter from the `TextField` init and call a function, which would modify the value.

But I will mark this answer as correct, because it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Really nice one! In which cases `clampedValue` can be useful? Stepper seems working not that good with it, and with plain modifications wrapped value seems enough

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Just using `wrappedValue` can cause conflicts, when chaining with a binding. A `Binding<...>` has a `wrappedValue`, meaning we can no longer access `wrappedValue` from `Clamping`. `Clamping`'s `wrappedValue` and `clampedValue` are the same, so `clampedValue` can be used when the other isn't accessible. In terms of the stepper not working that good with it: there are proper ways to clamp a stepper (as mentioned in the answer). I just used `Stepper` to give an easy way to test different numerical values.